# I want Flood Fill without stack and without recursion

Tags: graphics, recursion, stack, flood-fill

I wanted to know how to apply flood fill on array , my array is two dimensional , which contains times new roman font type letter boundry.
The boundry line contains 1's and inside and outside all 0's.
I want to fill all 1's instead 0 in only inside.
But i need a logic which do not required more memory.
So avoid recursion and stack or queue

Comment: Could you add an example of your array _before_ and _after_?

Comment: How do you intend to specify a point that is definitely interior (or exterior) to the outline?  (Imagine a grid as input -- which squares get filled in and which don't?)  This is necessary for disconnected glyphs (like ":") and any glyph whose outline contacts a boundary.

Comment: What type is contained in your array?  (Subtly asking how many more values that {0,1} are available to play with.)

Answer (score 4):

I don't normally do homework for other people, but I liked the challenge:

```
int c = -1;
while (c < 0)
{    
    /* Store breadcrumb trail, look to carry on */
    a[x][y] = c--;
    if (!hunt(0))
    {
        /* Nowhere to go, so back-track by looking for breadcrumb */
        a[x][y] = 1;
        c += 2;
        hunt(c);
    }
}

bool_t hunt(int v)
{
    if (a[x-1][y] == v)  { x--; return TRUE; }
    if (a[x+1][y] == v)  { x++; return TRUE; }
    if (a[x][y-1] == v)  { y--; return TRUE; }
    if (a[x][y+1] == v)  { y++; return TRUE; }
    return FALSE;
}
```

Note that this doesn't check for hitting the edges of the array.  Also, it assumes your array elements are e.g. `int`s, and that you're only using the values `0` and `1` in your image.

Answer (score 1):

Your task doesn't make much sense. If you have a typeface, you don't want to fill it with a flood fill, but rather render it directly as filled polygon instead. Determining which parts are in and out of the typeface, especially for a serif font, if not going to give good results reliably.

The typical schematic algorithm for a filled polygon goes like this (no stack or recursion required), and it can be applied to a bitmap as well under certain conditions (I'll come to that):

For each line (or column, whatever suits your data structure better), toggle the fill at each intersection of the virtual line you're following and all polygon lines (boundaries).

Assume this (could be the middle line of an O character):

```
00010010001001000
   ^  ^   ^  ^
   |  |   |  stop
   |  |   start
   |  stop
   start
```

Result:

```
00011110001111000
```

This works for bitmaps as well, but *only* if you actually always have two boundaries for start and stop.

Answer (score 0):

```
function LowMemFloodFill(pixel)
  FillPixel(pixel)
  Do
    didFill = false
    For each pixel
      If current pixel has been filled
        For each adjacent pixel
          If adjacent has not been filled
            FillPixel(adjacent)
            didFill = true
          End
        End
      End
    End
  While didFill
End
```

The catch is that you must be able to tell that a pixel has been filled (fill it with an unused color).  Also, this would be extremely slow.

Comment: RegularFloodFill is to LowMemFloodFill as QuickSort is to BubbleSort.

Answer (score -1):

You basically can't.  You have to store this information somewhere, because you have to know where else to start filling after you're done with your current section.  Recursion lets you do it implicitly.  Keeping your own stack lets you do it explicitly, with possibly some saving.  Oli Charlesworth does a cute thing by keeping an array of the same size as the picture, but that uses even more memory than recursion or keeping a stack of positions.

Comment: I don't use a separate array, `a[][]` is the image array.

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth: clever, but to keep this from going off the rails, you need to keep your trail from ever being adjacent to the colors being used.  Presumably, you're assuming that negative numbers can't be in the image.  If so, that means that the image has more bits allocated to it than are being used...